# Solve for x in the below equation:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, exponential-function

I got the value of x as 13/2 with the following solution. Are my steps right?[image: My solution]

[image: Question]

Comment: Nope, your simplification where the exponentials disappear is wrong.

Comment: *"Are my steps right?"* You can check this by plugging in your solution into the equation you started with.

Answer (score 6):

Rewrite 
$$27^x+3^{x+3}=12\cdot3^{2x}$$
as
$$(3^x)^3+27\cdot3^x=12\cdot(3^x)^2$$ which is of the form

$$z^3-12z^2+27z=0.$$

You can factor as

$$z(z-3)(z-9)=0$$ and the solutions in $x$ are $1$ and $2$. ($z=3^x=0$ is impossible.)

Answer (score 4):

No.$$\frac{3^{3x}+3^{x+3}}{3^{2x}}=3^x+3^{-x+3}\neq\frac{3x+(x+3)}{2x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

No, you forgot to take the base-3 logarithm on the RHS, so your equation after taking the base-3 logarithm should look like this: $$\frac{3x+(x+3)}{2x}=\log_312$$

Comment: This is the main error but it is also a mistake to go from $3x+(x+3)$ to $3x+x-3$.